# Why does this simple Java bytecode cause a StackOverflow error?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, bytecode, instrumentation, stack-overflow

I need to instrument native methods to make a simple static call before executing normally. Because the methods are native, I have to use the ["setNativePrefix" feature](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#setNativeMethodPrefix%28java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer,%20java.lang.String%29) and wrap the native methods with an intermediate call with the original method signature.

After what I thought was a simple bytecode change to accomplish this, I'm getting a StackOverflowError right before the wrapper method gets executed even though the stack is basically empty. Here's my test class:

```
public class SimpleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Perf.getPerf().highResCounter();
    }
}
```

Normally, that program would produce nothing on the console. However, my instrumented bytecode executes a println() before executing the native method $wrapper$highResCounter(). This can be seen in the relevant Perf class bytecode after instrumentation:

```
public long highResCounter() {
    getstatic PrintStream System.out
    ldc String Constant "this is an instrumented println"
    invokevirtual void PrintStream.println(String)
    aload 0
    invokevirtual long Perf.$wrapped$highResCounter()
    lreturn
}

public native long $wrapped$highResCounter();
```

I'm sort of new to Java bytecode, so I probably made a mistake here. Here's the output of the program, which shows that the println() gets executed, but somewhere after the first 
*invokevirtual* call a StackOverflowError is thrown:

```
this is an instrumented println call
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
   at com.foo.SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:17)
```

What could be causing this StackOverflowError? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you have the complete SimpleTest.java for us? Have you stepped through with a debugger? Maybe you aren't running what you think you are running. (Reminds me of a bug years ago I searched for hours until I realized that my classpath was pointing to old class files :)

Comment: That is the entirety of the class, minus import statement and package identifier. No static initializers or anything.

Comment: It also happens on any native method: like StrictMath.sin(). I don't think it has anything to do with Perf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no bugs in the code posted. The problem was being caused by invalid values for the MAX_STACK and MAX_LOCALS method attributes, which are usually calculated by the compiler.

The bytecode library I'm using, ASM, gives you the opportunity to calculate those values automatically, and I wasn't taking advantage of it. By changing the ASM ClassWriter constructor to the following I get error-free code:

```
int flags = ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS;
ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(flags);
```

[1] http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#COMPUTE_FRAMES

Comment: the verifier usually complains loudly about such cases

Comment: I should've thought of that. I think I've actually been there/done that. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Your highResCounter method is calling itself:

```
public long highResCounter() {
    [...]
    invokevirtual long Perf.$wrapped$highResCounter()
```

Do you have any more code you can show us to find out why?

Comment: It's not calling itself. It's calling the native method $wrapped$highResCounter. The non-native version is there only for me to make a call with before handing off responsibility to the native version.

Comment: What is $wrapped$highResCounter calling?

Comment: @nahsra - clearly *something* is directly or indirectly calling itself, or you wouldn't get a stack overflow exception.

Comment: @Jochen, Check out the native method behind it. The code here calls os::elapsed_counter() which doesn't call any other Perf methods. http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#xTe66uGm1PQ/trunk/jdk5.0_src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/perf.cpp&q=lang:c%2B%2B%20highResCounter&l=237.

Comment: @StephenC, I don't disagree - unless there's some less intuitive reason that StackOverflowErrors can be thrown.

Comment: Not really. They indicate that, well, your stack has overflown. Reason number one is a circular call, i.e. a function ending up being called again and again, until the stack is full. Don't you get a stack trace? You should see your highResCounter in there many many times. (That, or your stack is tiny, but that seems unlikely.)

Comment: I show the entire exception stack trace in the question. It's only got 1 entry.

Answer (score 0):

show the native function, it can also be a problem on its right own. iirc StackOverFlowError is trapped, so even JNI C code can cause it.

Comment: Plus, it happens with every native method I try, so it likely has nothing to do with the native code.